# Understanding methods behind and comparison - Find Prime Numbers

Tags: ruby, primes, coding-efficiency

### I would like to ask a few questions about finding prime numbers. The following code passed all the tests. Thanks!

**Solution: 1 - Question: Even though it passed all the tests, I am repeating "This is not a prime number" twice. How should I refactor to include num <=1 inside while loop so that I do not need to repeat "This is not a prime number?**

```
def is_it_prime(num)
    return "This is not a prime number" if num <= 1
    n = 2
    while n < num
      return "This is not a prime number" if num % n == 0
      n += 1
    end
    return "This is a prime number"
end
```

- check is_it_prime is defined.
- check argument count
- say that 7 is a prime number
- say that 100 is not a prime number
- say that a negative number is not a prime number
- say that 0 is not a prime number
- say that 1 is not a prime number
- say that 97 is a prime number

**Solution -2: For this code, I would like to know why num-1?**

```
def is_it_prime(num)
    return "This is not a prime number" if num <= 1
    (2..(num - 1)).each {|n|return "This is not a prime number" if num % n == 0 }
end
```

**For this code, I get an error for the following two values:**

```
puts is_it_prime(7) => 2..6
puts is_it_prime(97) => 2..96
```

**Solution -3:  Which one is more efficient? How should I check? 2..Math.sqrt(num) vs 2..(num-1).**

```
def is_it_prime(num)
    return "This is not a prime number" if num <= 1
    (2..Math.sqrt(num)).none? { |i| num % i == 0 }
    return "This is a prime number."
end
```

```
def is_it_prime(num)
    return "This is not a prime number" if num <= 1
    (2...(num -1)).all?{|m| num % m != 0 }
    return "This is a prime number."
end
```

**For these two sets of code, I get the same error.Why is it giving this result**

```
puts is_it_prime(100) => This is a prime number.
```

Comment: Which is the most efficient? This one: `require 'prime'; Prime.prime?(97)`. On a serious note, you only ever need to check up to square root: any non-prime `n` has some `a` and `b`  such that `a * b == p`; if `a` is greater than square root, then `b` is surely smaller, so any pair will be found by the time square root is tested.

Comment: @Amadan I know that in Ruby, I can use it. However, in this coding challenge, require 'prime' is not allowed to be used.

Comment: @Horacio Thanks for your advice. I am new to Ruby and have read stack overflow ruby prime number related posts, read a few articles and watched youtube. However I still couldn't understand questions raised in the question. After I study more, I am sure I will understand. For the time being while I am learning (started semester one month ago), I need a bit of direction from other experienced professionals/ senior students. I will also continue to study on my own. Thanks Cheers

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one post. I see four separate questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Your second code fails because Ruby will return the value of the last evaluated expression if it reaches the end of the method without processing a `return` statement. The last expression was `(2..(num - 1)).each { ... }`, and `each` returns the object it was invoked on. Make sure you return something either during, or after `each`.

Af for your third code, there is no difference in efficiency between `all? { |a| a == b }` and `none? { a != b }`. They are completely equivalent. As explained in comments, testing up to square root is sufficient, and testing up to `n-1` is overkill. But the error is because you evaluate whether something is a prime or not, and then *discard this information* and print `"This is a prime number."` regardless.

In order to not repeat yourself, you could do several different things. Separate the test from the printing:

```
def is_it_prime(num)
  return true if num <= 1
  n = 2
  limit = Math.sqrt(num)
  while n <= limit
    return false if num % n == 0
    n += 1
  end
  return true
end

def is_it_prime(num)
  if is_it_prime_for_real(num)
    return "This is a prime number"
  else
    return "This is not a prime number" 
  end
end
```

Make a compound test:

```
def is_it_prime(num)
  if num <= 1 or (2..Math.sqrt(num)).all? { |m| num % m != 0 }
    "This is not a prime number" 
  else
    "This is a prime number"
  end
end
```

Use constants to avoid duplicating literals:

```
IS_PRIME = "This is a prime number"
IS_NOT_PRIME = "This is not a prime number"
def is_it_prime(num)
  return IS_NOT_PRIME if num <= 1
  return IS_PRIME if (2..Math.sqrt(num)).none? { |m| (num % m).zero? }
  IS_NOT_PRIME
end
```

...

Comment: Thanks Amadan for your answer!  `def is_it_prime(num)
    return "This is not a prime number" if num <= 1
    (2..(num - 1)).each {|n|return "This is not a prime number" if num % n == 0 }
    return "This is a prime number"
end ` sqrt vs n-1 = Is it about O(log(n)) and O(sqrt(n))? (I have not studied Discrete Maths, Datastructure and algorithm subjects.) Would that be possible for you to give me a link to read up? Thanks again. Much appreciated!

Comment: Solution-3 - Thanks@Amadan! I will learn more theory and do more practice! after @Amadan answer `def is_it_prime(num)
    return "This is not a prime number" if num <= 1
    if (2..Math.sqrt(num)).none? { |i| num % i == 0 }
        return "This is not a prime numer" 
    else 
        return "This is a prime number."
    end 
end `

Comment: @Thanks Amadan for your updated answers. They really helps me to understand the concepts better!